# Ordenar la salida de Toast/Alert (no plugin, es desde cero)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

---

Tengo esta función que muestra un mensaje dependiendo del estado "error, success, warning, etc"....
Y al agregar nueva alerta, esta se pone debajo así sucesivamente, lo que quiero hacer es invertirlo, o sea el último que sea el de arriba.

Ejemplo:
*En vez de*:

- Alerta 1
- Alerta 2
- Alerta 3

*Quiero que sea*:

- Alerta 3
- Alerta 2
- Alerta 1

Código

```
alert: function({size = 24, libreria, icono, color, mensaje, segundos = 3}) {

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1654 * 12)) + segundos; // Es solo para identificar el id

    this.createSvg({size, libreria, icono, bloqueHtml:'.Toast--icon'});
    id = `ToastBox_${random}`;
    html = $("#ToastBoxes").append(`<div id="${id}" class="Toast Toast--${color}"><span class="Toast--icon"></span><span class="Toast--text">${mensaje}</span></div>`).addClass('show');
    //ModalBox.cerrar();

    $('.Toast').each(function(index, value) {
      // Es 3s por defectos 
      setTimeout(function(){
         // ex: $("#ToastBox_15156").remove().fadeOut(350);
         $("#"+value.id).remove().fadeOut(this.setTime);
      }, segundos * 1000);
   });

   return html;
},
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, espero haberme expresado bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando el método `append()` de *jQuery* el cual adiciona el elemento al final, solo cámbialo por `prepend()` y se incrustara al inicio, así:

```js
html = $("#ToastBoxes").prepend(`<div id="${id}" class="Toast Toast--${color}"><span class="Toast--icon"></span><span class="Toast--text">${mensaje}</span></div>`).addClass('show');
```

[Aquí esta su documentación](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

También tienes la opción de posicionarlo con **Flexbox** de **CSS** y usar la propiedad `flex-direction`, ejemplo, de la siguiente manera:

```css
#ToastBoxes{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder y tu tiempo, me había olvidado de que existia .prepend() ya que nunca la había usado!

Comment: Con todo gusto..!! recuerda que como mencione **Flexbox** también te proporciona mucho dinamismo en este caso ;)